# Problem installing youtube lens

Tags: youtube

I get an `E: Unable to locate package lens-video` error after running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install lens-video scope-youtube
```

I have the video lens in DASH working.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the PPA?

Try adding this ppa to the list: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/lenses` and after adding try installing the lens

Comment: hey @devav2 does the scope work with the default video lens in ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Nope. Youtube scope wont work with the default video lens in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Hi, thnx for helping, I am running 12.04 and I'm pretty sure I did the sudo add apt thing as you wrote ( I definitely did an add-apt can't remember if it was exactly the same) I'll try again this evening.

Comment: it won't work if you're running 12.04

Answer (score 0):

The scope-youtube no longer uses lens-videos lens but yavol, so you need to:

- sudo apt-get install scope-youtube yavol

After that, just log-out/back-in and it should be there.